# cannot get value of parameter in Dialogflow when I create intent using API

Tags: dialogflow-es

1. What I want

I want to get value of parameter in Dialogflow when I create intent using API.

For example, When I say "I like orange", Dialogflow return "You like orange".

2. What I did

First, I created Entities.
It's name of fruits.

[Entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BqDf.png)

And, I created intent using v2beta1 API.

[v2beta1/projects.agent.intents/batchUpdate](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents/batchUpdate)

The payload is as follows.

```
{
  "intentBatchInline": {
    "intents": [
      {
        "displayName": "test flruits",
        "messages": [
          {
            "text": {
              "text": [
                "$fruits"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "trainingPhrases": [
          {
            "parts": [
              {
                "text": "i like "
              },
              {
                "text": "fruits",
                "entityType": "@fruits",
                "alias": "fruits",
                "userDefined": true
              }
            ],
            "type": "EXAMPLE"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "languageCode": "en"
}
```

So, I trained using [Method: projects.agent.train](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent/train).

And, I called intent using tester.
But, I cannot get value of parameter!

[cannot get value of parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kerrO.png)

And, I trained agent using ML Settings.
But, I cannot get value of parameter!

[ML Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xpMi.png)

But after that, I pushed SAVE button in the page of the intent.
"Agent training started" has appeared.

[Agent training started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jyhZ.png)

And, fix problem.
I can get "orange"!!

[orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTcHA.png)

But, I want to set only using API.
I don't want to use browser.

How should I do?

Comment: the question is tagged dialogflow-cx, but from your screenshots you're using dialogflow-es version, please change the tag accordingly to receive meaningful replies

Comment: @fcagnola
Thank you for your comment!
I fixed the tag.